# Extracting elevation data using Google Earth?

Tags: elevation, xml, google-earth-pro

How do I extract multiple elevation values for a particular area in Google-Earth all at once?

I've only been able to manually pick them one by one when I enter the long. and lat. for each point.

Comment: why don´t you use srtm or aster gdem data? both are free data and have the same resolution. I think Google Earth uses srtm data

Comment: @Pau GE uses SRTM data mostly, but I've read that they use higher-resolution data in some areas. I don't think there's any way to query GE and find out where the elevation data it's using for a certain point comes from though.

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question completely but I have found for finding elevation going to https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ works better. Earth explorer gives you access to different satellite data and EarthExplorer you can manually choose the area you are attempting to study by entering in the Longitude and latitude or just place markers on the map itself. Once you have that area you want, download the tiff file and import into any of the GIS or Remote sensing software like ArcMap, QGis or Terrset (Idrisi Selva). The elevation data should then be available for any point you scroll over or search, and this allows you to work with the points within the area you want.